# Enabling CORS Support in Rasa Core HTTP API

Tags: angular, cors, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I am experimenting with the default [MoodBot example](https://core.rasa.com/tutorial_basics.html) of Rasa Core framework. I have developed a simple Angular 5 app to serve as a front-end for the conversation flow. The Rasa HTTP API is run on a Linux-based back-end server at port 5005 (let's call it http://my.very.own.server:5005/) using the following command:

```
python3 -m rasa_core.server -d models/dialogue -u models/nlu/default/current -o out.log
```

I can communicate with the server using Postman application and get a valid response. But when I try the same from my Angular app, it returns a `404 (Not found)` error.

**Using postman (working):**

*POST*: my.very.own.server:5005/conversations/default/parse
*Body of the request*: {"query":"hi"}
*Headers*: Content-Type: application/json
*Response*: Success (200) - Valid JSON content received

**Using Angular app (not working):**

```
public getResponse(query: string) {

  let finalUrl: string = "http://my.very.own.server/" + "conversations/default/parse/";

  let data = {
    'query' : query
  }
  return this.http.post(
      `${finalUrl}`, data
    ).map(res => {
      return res.json()
    })
}

// Call the method using:

getResponse("hi").subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

This results in a console error:

```
Failed to load http://my.very.own.server:5005/conversations/default/parse/:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

What I have tried:

1. I tried running the Rasa server with an additional `--cors` parameter (as seen [here](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_core/issues/143)):

`python3 -m rasa_core.server -d models/dialogue -u models/nlu/default/current -o out.log --cors ["*"]`

2. I tried adding `"cors_origins" : ["*"]` to the `nlu_model_config.json` file (as seen [here](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu/issues/712)).

Both ways made no difference. What am I doing wrong here, and what can I do to properly enable CORS support from the Rasa HTTP API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recently fixed this, so you'll need [this PR](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_core/commit/d63f55c44cd919d2031311201caa1c26c94cb365) . For now you'll have to clone master, but we're releasing a new version 0.9 soon so it'll be available on pypi as well.